# Can you invoice an event participant

Tags: invoice

I have a few participants registered for an event that haven't paid.  Is there a way to invoice them from the the event report?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to CiviCRM SE!

You can email an invoice for any contribution type including events. You can find more information here:

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/contributions/invoicing/

Hope this helps!